# Refresh aliases without reboot?

Tags: command-line, bash, reboot, bashrc, alias

After adding a new alias to `/etc/bash.bashrc` I couldn't use the alias unless I've rebooted via executing `reboot`.

I would prefer not to use `reboot` is because it's annoying to logout, wait 2-4 seconds, and login again to my VPS environment.

Given I also don't want to work with a subshell or a separate shell in a new window, just for that, I ask:

Must I `reboot`? Is there no way to use the alias in the same shell without rebooting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `source /etc/bash.bashrc` to have your current shell re-read the file.

Answer (score 10):

You can load the new aliases without reboot using `source` command

```
source /etc/bash.bashrc
```

> [bash source](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html)
>
> . (source or dot operator)
>
> Read and execute commands from the filename argument in the current
>   shell context.
>
> Syntax
>         . filename [arguments]
>
> ```
>   source filename [arguments]
> ```
>
> source is a synonym for dot/period '.' in bash, but not in POSIX sh,
>   so for maximum compatibility use the period.
>
> When a script is run using source it runs within the existing shell,
>   any variables created or modified by the script will remain available
>   after the script completes. In contrast if the script is run just as
>   filename, then a separate subshell (with a completely separate set of
>   variables) would be spawned to run the script.